# How to add data inside nested array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose for database functionalities in my nodejs project.Below is my model.

Here is the POST request:

[image]

In MongoDb data is saving like this :

[image]

Here `owers` array is empty.
**expense.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ExpenseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  userid:{
      type: String,
      required: true
  },
  owers:[{
     owerid:{
        type: String
      },
     amt:{
       type: Number  
     }
    }],
  name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  amount:{
      type: Number,
      require: true
  }
});

const expense = mongoose.model('expense',ExpenseSchema);
module.exports = expense;
```

Whenever I am trying to insert something array is showing empty.Below is my code:

**addExpense.js**

const expense = require('../models/expense.js');

const addExpense = async (req,res) => {

```
const {name,amount,owerid,amt} = req.body;
console.log(name + " " + owerid);
const {userid} = req.params;

const expens = new expense({userid,name,amount});

try{
    const data = await expens.save();
    expens.owers.push({"owerid":owerid,"amt":amt});
    res.send({"id":data._id}); 
}
catch(error){
    res.send(error);
}
};

module.exports = {addExpense};
```

Someone let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your "addExpense.js" code basically says "get whatever comes in the request and store as a new document".  What do you send in the request body, what you expect to be saved in the db?

Comment: Yeah thats what I want but value of `owerid` and `amt` is not storing in array.Everything else is storing.

Comment: Do you send them as an array? Sorry if my comment was not clear, but the question doesn't make much sense without an example of the data you are trying to save.

Comment: I have updated my post take a look

Comment: HTTP is a text based protocol, you know. Postman actually converts this "image" to an http request and sends the json in the request body. The same body that your application recieves in `req.body`. Try to "Save" the request from Postman and you will see you send a flat object. There is no `owers` array there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Enter owers value like that]

```
Try This
   const {name,amount,owers} = req.body;
        console.log(name + " " + owerid);
        const {userid} = req.params;
        
        const expens = new expense({userid,name,amount});
        
        try{
            const data = await expens.save();
        
           //After you can push multiple data like that
        
          JSON.parse(owers).map((value) => {
            data.owers.push({
                owerid: value.owerid,
                amt: value.amt
            })
        })
        
           data.save()
        
            res.send({"id":data._id}); 
        }
        catch(error){
            res.send(error);
        }
```